# Inadvertently deleted admin clusterrole and can't access cluster resources

Tags: kubernetes

I deleted my cluster-admin role via kubectl using:

`kubectl delete clusterrole cluster-admin`

Not sure what I expected, but now I don't have access to the cluster from my account. Any attempt to get or change resources using kubectl returns a 403, Forbidden.
Is there anything I can do to revert this change without blowing away the cluster and creating a new one? I have a managed cluster on Digital Ocean.

Comment: Could you run any `kubectl` command or could you login to your cluster from Digital Ocean portal?

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#auto-reconciliation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Not sure what I expected, but now I don't have access to the cluster from my account.

If none of the `kubectl` commands actually work, unfortunately you will not be able to create a new cluster role. The problem is that you won't be able to do anything without an admin role. You can try creating the `cluster-admin` role directly through the API (not using kubectl), but if that doesn't help you have to recreate the cluster.

Comment: Just to share, https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#auto-reconciliation, now sure when he deleted that clusterrole it has annotation or not. if there restarting may be helpful. `Auto-reconciliation is enabled by default if the RBAC authorizer is active.` :D

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I was not able to do anything myself, but since this is a managed cluster, the Digital Ocean support team was able to "recycle the master" which ended up re-creating the role thus returning kubectl abilities to me.

Answer (score 1):

Try applying this YAML to creaste the new Cluster role

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  annotations:
    rbac.authorization.kubernetes.io/autoupdate: "true"
  labels:
    kubernetes.io/bootstrapping: rbac-defaults
  name: cluster-admin
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - '*'
  resources:
  - '*'
  verbs:
  - '*'
- nonResourceURLs:
  - '*'
  verbs:
  - '*'
```

apply the YAML file changes

```
kubectl apply -f <filename>.yaml
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, unfortunately this command still returned a 403.